# Connect to Windows 10 Docker daemon from Ubuntu Bash

Tags: docker, windows-10

I'm trying to do something fairly non-standard, so I'm not sure how successful I'm going to be.

I've installed "Docker for Windows", and I'm able to use it fine from PowerShell.

I would like to be able to use a proper Linux environment though, so I've installed the new Ubuntu Bash prompt for Windows 10.

I've successfully built the latest Docker client in Ubuntu/Bash. However when I run "docker ps", I get:

> Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the Docker daemon running on this host?

I had hoped that it might just work.

Is it possible to connect to a Docker daemon running in Windows from Ubuntu/Bash?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I figured it out. It was surprisingly simple. I just had to set the following...

```
export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://127.0.0.1:2375
```

This is actually a really cool setup.

A very fast, efficient Docker engine running in a type 2 hypervisor, and a proper Ubuntu-based development environment. Nice :-)

Notice: as @BSalita mentioned in the comment, the Docker service must be running with "Expose daemon on tcp://localhost:2375 without TLS" enabled, which can be found in the general section in Docker Settings (right click on the system tray icon then "Settings..."). This option is not checked by default.

Comment: Thanks so much for coming back and giving the solution. Works like a charm !

Comment: One issue I discovered with this setup. There doesn't seem to be any way to mount volumes from the command line.

Comment: You can, but not files from the Ubuntu user space. Since the host is on a linux VM, in hyper-v, on windows it can't access the files in the "Ubuntu on Windows" magic space.You have to:
1. share your windows drives to your docker host (you do this from the docker settings)
2. use windows paths when mounting, like `c:/Users/roman/Desktop`, and NOT linux paths (`/mnt/c/Users/roman/Desktop`)

Comment: I needed to do one other thing besides setting DOCKER_HOST. I had to check the box in Docker Settings->General->Expose daemon on tcp://localhost:2375 without TLS.